# Showing "updating..." message while Manipulate is re-evaluating

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, button, scheduling

Is it possible to show a fixed text such as *"updating..."* instead of the last result shown, when `Manipulate` is re-evaluating an expression (in a slow evaluation context)? How to do it?

More precisely, I have a `Button` element in the set of controls, and it is the action triggered by the button the one that slows down the process, and *not* the results shown in the `Manipulate` sentence themselves.

This could be a MWE for what I mean:

```
Manipulate[result,
 {{x, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None},
 {{y, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None},
 Button["Calculate", Pause[2]; result = x + y],
 TrackedSymbols :> {result},
 Initialization -> Clear[result, x, y]]
```

In this example, the values for two integer numbers `x` and `y` are selected using their respective slider controls, and then a button is used to perform some calculations based on them. Finally, results based on those calculations are shown using `Manipulate`.

So, regarding this example, my question is: how can I show the text *"updating..."* while the button is *thinking*?

If you think there would be an easier solution in case it was not the button but the expression to be shown by `Manipulate` the one that takes some long time to be executed, I think I could also modify my real problem to be like that. The MWE could be like this:

```
Manipulate[Pause[2]; parameters[[1]] + parameters[[2]],
 {{a, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None},
 {{b, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None},
 Button["Calculate", parameters = {a, b}], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {parameters}, 
 Initialization -> (Clear[a, b, parameters]; parameters = {5, 5})]
```

It would be also OK if the text *"updating..."* appeared *in the button*, temporarily replacing the *"Calculate"* text. It would be a little bit strange, but also valid.

I look forward to your solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with the code and I finally found a way to do what I wanted. In the meanwhile, I think I've also better understood the behaviour of `Manipulate`.

This is my solution; it deals with the second MWE I posted:

```
Manipulate[

 (* === Calculations that are triggered each time there is a change
        in tracked symbols —'parameters', in this case: === *)

 message = "Updating..."; result = "";
 Pause[2];
 result = parameters[[1]] + parameters[[2]];
 message = "Ready";

 (* === Results to be shown: === *)

 Column[{Dynamic[message], Dynamic[result]}],

 (* === Controls: === *)

 {{a, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None}, 
 {{b, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, AppearanceElements -> None}, 
 Button["Calculate", parameters = {a, b}],

 (* === Other settings: === *)

 TrackedSymbols :> {parameters},
 Initialization -> (
   Clear[a, b, parameters, message, result];
   parameters = {5, 5}; result = 10; message = "Ready"
   )]
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this fits your needs, but it works for me :P

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0, result = {}, panel, acc, message},
 Dynamic[Refresh[
   Overlay[
    {panel, message},
    Dynamic@Switch[acc, 0, {1}, _, {1, 2}],
    Dynamic@Switch[acc, 0, 1, _, 2]
    , Alignment -> Center],
   None]]
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   acc = 0;
   panel = Column[Print["CCreating column"]; {
      Dynamic@result,
      Slider[Dynamic@a, {0, 1}],
      Slider[Dynamic@b, {0, 1}],
      Button["Calculate", acc = 1; FinishDynamic[]; Pause[2]; 
       result = {a, b}; acc = 0;, Method -> "Queued"]
      }];

 message = 
   Framed["Updating...", Background -> GrayLevel@.6]), BaseStyle -> Selectable -> False]
```

> [image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've just added my own answer, that better fits my needs. You can comment on it, if you want.