# Showing updating message in Dynamic with UpdateInterval

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, scheduling

I am creating an interface which needs to repeat an operation every few seconds. The operation itself is expensive but faster than the update interval of the interface.

I would like to have some visual feedback to know every time the operation starts and ends but I have not been able to find a solution that works well.

This is what I have now:

```
expensive[k_] := (Pause[2]; k + 1)

DynamicModule[{k = 0, status = "not calculating"},
 {
  Dynamic[
   Refresh[status = "calculating";
    k = expensive[k];
    status = "not calculating",
    UpdateInterval -> 5, TrackedSymbols :> {}]],

  Dynamic[{status, k}, TrackedSymbols :> {status}]
  }
 ]
```

Does anyone know how why it is not working and how to fix it?

This question is related to [Showing "updating..." message while Manipulate is re-evaluating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59286/showing-updating-message-while-manipulate-is-re-evaluating) but the refresh is triggered by an UpdateInterval instead of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Dynamic` is using preemptive link and it is theoretically possible to do what you need. However, there are no tools to manage evaluation precisely (one could try with `FinishDynamic[]`). At the moment you are using one link which is busy so it can't update second `Dynamic`.

You can't count on specific order of tasks but you can send one to main link by using `SynchronousUpdating -> False`:

```
expensive[k_] := (Pause[2]; k + 1)

DynamicModule[{k = 0, status = "not calculating"}, 
  {Dynamic[
    Refresh[
      status = "calculating"; 
      k = expensive[k];
      status = "not calculating"
      , 
      UpdateInterval -> 5, 
      TrackedSymbols :> {}
    ]
    , 
    SynchronousUpdating -> False
  ], 
  Dynamic[{status, k}, TrackedSymbols :> {status}]}
]
```

p.s. are you sure you don't want to use `ScheduledTasks`?

Comment: Thank you Kuba. This works! For now I manage evaluation just with a UpdateInterval->If[autoUpdate, 5, Infinity]. Maybe down the road I switch to a ScheduledTask, but I generally try to avoid those. I once tried to use it for a once per day task and it was not reliable at all. Maybe for tasks with a shorter period it works better.